# Is InfiniteScroll not working on ionic 3?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I'm having trouble implementing Infinite-scroll in my `IONIC 3` application

This is my `home.html`:

```
<div paddign>
  <ion-searchbar (ionInput)="getItems($event)" placeholder="Pesquisar"></ion-searchbar>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="itemTapped($event, item)">
        <ion-thumbnail item-left>
            <img [src]="item.imagem">
        </ion-thumbnail>
        <h2 style="color:#886AEA">{{ item?.nome }}</h2>
        <p>Rua: {{ item?.rua }} - {{ item?.numero }}</p>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>

    <ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)">
      <ion-infinite-scroll-content
        loadingSpinner="bubbles"
        loadingText="Loading more data...">
      </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
    </ion-infinite-scroll>
</div>
```

And this is my `home.ts`:

```
items: any[];

constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private toast: ToastController,
    public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public menu: MenuController) {
    this.initializeItems();
}

doInfinite(infiniteScroll) {
    console.log('Begin async operation');

    setTimeout(() => {
        for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            this.items.push( this.items.length );
        }

        console.log('Async operation has ended');
        infiniteScroll.complete();
    }, 500);
}
```

However this function works only at the end of my application.

[image]

This is a vídeo of my aplicattion

[image]

Comment: Can you please put your code using https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: Sorry, my list is huge.

Comment: well, you could probably create a fake list returned by a simple service to illustrate your point. The point of the stackblitz is to create a [mcve] that will greatly improve the quality of your question, and attract various answers that can solve your problem.

Comment: not sure what you mean with "works only at the end of my application", care to expand on the problem that you're seeing?

Comment: I edited my question with a GIF

Comment: Not sure what the problem is, in that gif looks like infinite scroll is working as intended, what is wrong in it? is it that you see the loading text? That is part of infinite scroll. You can change that in the settings: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/infinite-scroll/InfiniteScroll/#input-properties

Comment: First is loaded all 200 items and after that infinityScroll works, it does not start at the beginning, but at the end of my application.

Comment: My searchbar will not work correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing `this.items.push( this.items.length );` which means the the length of the `items` is being pushed into the `items[]`.

Try pushing the object itself and it would work.

```
items: any[];

constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private toast: ToastController,
    public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public menu: MenuController) {
    this.initializeItems();
}

doInfinite(infiniteScroll) {
    console.log('Begin async operation');

    setTimeout(() => {
        for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            this.items.push( this.items[length] );
        }

        console.log('Async operation has ended');
        infiniteScroll.complete();
    }, 500);
}
```

**NOTE:**
You should define the start and end variables so that you won't be ended up displaying the same item again and again.

Comment: How to define the start and end variables please send me a code with start and end variables how should be?

Answer (score 2):

From your question & the comments I believe the effect you want to achieve, is the list loading the next set of list items before the user reaches the end of the list.
As of right now, the `doInfinite($event)` event is triggered only after the user has scrolled to the end of the list. You will want to trigger this event a little before the end.

To do that, add the attribute `threshold` to the html. Threshold defines the point at which `doInfinite($event)` should be triggered. For example, if the threshold value is 25%, the event will be triggered when the user is 25% from the end of the list aka once 75% of the list has been scrolled through.

The html will now look like :

```
<div paddign>
  <ion-searchbar (ionInput)="getItems($event)" placeholder="Pesquisar"></ion-searchbar>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="itemTapped($event, item)">
      <ion-thumbnail item-left>
        <img [src]="item.imagem">
      </ion-thumbnail>
      <h2 style="color:#886AEA">{{ item?.nome }}</h2>
      <p>Rua: {{ item?.rua }} - {{ item?.numero }}</p>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

  <ion-infinite-scroll threshold="25%" (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)">
    <ion-infinite-scroll-content
      loadingSpinner="bubbles"
      loadingText="Loading more data...">
    </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
  </ion-infinite-scroll>
</div>
```

From Ionic's [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/infinite-scroll/InfiniteScroll/#input-properties)

> The threshold distance from the bottom of the content to call the infinite output event when scrolled. The threshold value can be either a percent, or in pixels. For example, use the value of 10% for the infinite output event to get called when the user has scrolled 10% from the bottom of the page. Use the value 100px when the scroll is within 100 pixels from the bottom of the page. Default is 15%.

Answer (score 0):

[your `ion-list` needs to be wrapped by a `ion-content`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/infinite-scroll/InfiniteScroll/), otherwise you'll get an error:

> ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[InfiniteScroll -> Content]: 
>     StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[InfiniteScroll -> Content]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for Content!

```
<div paddign>
  <ion-searchbar (ionInput)="getItems($event)" placeholder="Pesquisar"></ion-searchbar>
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="itemTapped($event, item)">
          <ion-thumbnail item-left>
              <img [src]="item.imagem">
          </ion-thumbnail>
          <h2 style="color:#886AEA">{{ item?.nome }}</h2>
          <p>Rua: {{ item?.rua }} - {{ item?.numero }}</p>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>

      <ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)">
        <ion-infinite-scroll-content
          loadingSpinner="bubbles"
          loadingText="Loading more data...">
        </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
      </ion-infinite-scroll>
    </ion-content>
</div>
```

[Check the live example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-uw2dyv?file=app%2Fapp.html)

---

### Settings

If your question is about seeing the "loading" text, check out the [settings for infinite scroll](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/infinite-scroll/InfiniteScroll/#input-properties):

### Loading new elements on the top

> **position**  string
>   The position of the infinite scroll element. The value can be either top or bottom. Default is bottom.

Use this if you want your app to add items to the top.

### Loading earlier

> **threshold** string
>   The threshold distance from the bottom of the content to call the infinite output event when scrolled. The threshold value can be either a percent, or in pixels. For example, use the value of 10% for the infinite output event to get called when the user has scrolled 10% from the bottom of the page. Use the value 100px when the scroll is within 100 pixels from the bottom of the page. Default is 15%.

Use this if you want it to load extra items earlier so you don't see the "loading" text.